# Parsing CVS to JSON tree with parent IDs

Tags: java, javascript, json, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have a problem with parsing my big (~100K rows) CVS file:

```
ID, FirstName, LastName, Division, Date, Parent_ID1, Parent_ID2, Parent_ID3
1,  TestName1, TestLastName1, Division1, 1.1.2001, , , ,   
2,  TestName2, TestLastName2, Division2, 2.5.2006,1, , ,
3,  TestName3, TestLastName3, Division3, 2.4.2007,2,1, , 
4,  TestName4, TestLastName4, Division4, 2.5.2002,3,2,1, 
5,  TestName5, TestLastName5, Division5, 2.5.2008,4,3,2,
6,  TestName6, TestLastName6, Division6, 2.6.2006,5,2,1,
7,  TestName7, TestLastName7, Division7, 7.5.2004,6,3,2,
8,  TestName8, TestLastName8, Division8, 4.6.2001,7,6,3,
```

....

where id=1 - root.

parent_id1 -> closest parent, parent_id2 -> next parent and etc.

Want to draw Sunburst with Distortion like here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1306365
JSON tree example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1306365/bfecc11c6d2690499430813141824cd788a37728/readme.json

Can I create JSON tree with JAVA with all parent-children dependencies?
Or I should use D3 library for that only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what have you tried? what is "1-root"? and you certainly can create JSON with java.

Comment: what is "1-root"? -> first parent element.  I don't know how to put chain of parents objects to children with JAVA